# FileField / ImageField migration doesn't apply

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, imagefield

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this Django error, I have my models created like this :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

# Create your models here.


class Album(models.Model):
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title


class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # file = models.ImageField(upload_to=Album.album_title, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    file_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    file_type = models.Choices('Raw', 'JPEG')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.album) + "ID.{:0>3}".format(self.id)
```

If I make the migrations like this, everything works fine, but whenever I uncommented the line :

`file = models.ImageField(upload_to=Album.album_title, null=True, blank=True)`
in my class Photo, I can't do migrations.

When I run the `python3 manage.py make migrations` code I have this stack trace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adamspierredavid/Documents/django/crueltouch/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/adamspierredavid/Documents/django/crueltouch/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 190, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 227, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 141, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 99, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 63, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(_arg_value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 271, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 201, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 88, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 353, in serializer_factory
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10a1bcfd0>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

I went to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing to see what it says but I couldn't find something understandable (in my level) to fix the issue. Problem is that in a previous project, when I wanted to add images, Django asked me to install Pillow, and after I did, my code worked. I could do migrations but now, nothing. I'm using Postgres as my database.

Thank you guys for helping. (P.S: I'm a beginner in learning Django)

Comment: Have you installed pillow ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've found the error in my code, it should be upload_to="Album.album_title", I forgot the quote, that's why it was not working. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is `ImageField`, this has the field `upload_to` which is supposed to be a path name, it can't be pointing to a class `Album` whose instance is yet to be created. If your `Photo` should be saved based on `album` field I suppose seeing the
code line `file = models.ImageField(upload_to=Album.album_title, null=True, blank=True)` and line `album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, I consider here that, you want to save `file` based on the `album` you pointing to.

you can try something like this

```
def get_path(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.file.album_title, filename)
```

and your `file` line code should look like

`file = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_path, null=True, blank=True)`

---

what you doing here is, you define a function that makes sure your path is set dynamically based on your inputs. inside function `get_upload_path` you can make changes to path structure as you like.

for more insights, you can refer to this doc
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

`Imagefield` inherits from `FileField` in django models, so this doc is sufficient.